# I don't go to bed early on Saturdays

Tags: grammar

1. I don't go to bed early on Saturdays.
2. Sometimes I go to bed early on Saturdays, but sometimes I don't go to bed early on Saturdays.
3. I don't go to bed early on Saturdays at all.

---

Does #1 mean #2 or #3? Is #1 a partial negation?

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 implies number 3, but it could also mean:

> Usually I don't go to bed early on Saturdays.

The general statement "I don't do X" often means "I never do X" but can mean "I do not normally do X".  Only context or a more specific  statement can tell the reader or listener which is meant.